# Problemas ao gerar uma PartialView com BeginCollectionItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Com a intenção de criar um ação para Adc/Deletar dados dinamicamente a uma tabela com relação 1 para Muitas, o .net retorna a exceção *"**Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.**"* quando chamo a *PartialView* tento visualizar a view, segue os *Models*, *viewModels*, *Controller*, *View* e *PartialView*...

**Models**

```
public class Candidato
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string sexo { get; set; }
}

public class CandidatoEP
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_candidato { get; set; }
    public string empresa { get; set; }
    public string cargo { get; set; }
    public DateTime inicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime fim { get; set; }
    public string obsEp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("id_candidato")]
    public virtual Candidato candidato { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class NovoCandidato
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o Nome")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o CPF")]
    [Display(Name = "CPF")]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o Sexo")]
    [Display(Name = "Sexo")]
    public string sexo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CandidatoEP> CandidatoEPs { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Novo()
{
    var novoCandidato = new CandidatoNovo();
    return View(novoCandidato);
}
```

**View** (*parte onde insiro a PartialView*)

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
    <label>Experiência <small>(opcional)</small></label>
    <div class="dc-form-inside">

        @foreach (var Experiencia in Model.CandidatoEPs)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_AddCandidatoExp", Experiencia);
        }

        <a href="#" class="control-add-box">+ Adicionar Experiência</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**PartialView**

```
@model Site.ViewModels.CandidatoNovo

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("CandidatoEPs"))
{
    <div class="dc-box-clonar form experiencia">
        <a href="#" class="fechar-form botao"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">

            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.empresa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Empresa onde trabalhou" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">

            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.id_departamento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Departamento" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">

            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.cargo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Função exercida" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">

            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.inicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Início (MM/AAAA)" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">

            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.fim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Fim (MM/AAAA)" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:30px;">

            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.obsEp, new { @class = "dc-textarea form-control", @placeholder = "Descreva as atividades exercidas na função...", @rows = "3" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.obsEp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Ai, eu uso uma função no js para adicionar multiplos box de experiencia.

**Javascript**

```
$('.dc-box-clonar').hide();
$('.control-add-box').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newElem = $(this).parent().find('.dc-box-clonar:first').clone();
    newElem.find('input').val('');
    newElem.prependTo($(this).parent()).show();
    var height = $(this).prev('.dc-box-clonar').outerHeight(true);

    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 520 }, 600);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolvendo rapidamente o problema, seria algo assim:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
    <label>Experiência <small>(opcional)</small></label>
    <div class="dc-form-inside">

        @if (Model != null && Model.CandidatoEPs != null) 
        {
            foreach (var Experiencia in Model.CandidatoEPs)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_AddCandidatoExp", Experiencia);
            }
        }

        <a href="#" class="control-add-box">+ Adicionar Experiência</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pra você adicionar a experiência, use algo assim:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#adicionar-nova-experiencia").click(function () {
                $.get('/Experiencia/NovaLinha', function (template) {
                    $("#area-experiencias").append(template); /* Você pode ainda colocar .then($(...)); */
                });
            });
        </script>
```

E no *Controller* (usando `Guid`):

```
    public ActionResult NovaLinha()
    {
        return PartialView("_LinhaExperiencia", new Experiencia { ExperienciaId = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }
```

Usando `int`:

```
    public ActionResult NovaLinha()
    {
        return PartialView("_LinhaExperiencia", new Experiencia());
    }
```

Com `int` a chave não é definida em *Controller* porque a definição da chave fica a cargo do banco de dados, no momento em que você salva o registro.

O *Controller* recebe o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Novo(CandidatoNovo candidatoNovo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    { 
        /* Aqui candidatoNovo.CandidatoEPs está preenchido */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: E Cigano, porque ao colocar @if na view o problema foi resolvido?

Comment: Porque as referências podem vir nulas. Eu não sei como você está preenchendo, então confiro as variáveis antes de tentar imprimir qualquer coisa.

Comment: Aqui a Id da Experiencia está declado como int, ai quando se coloca Guid retorna um erro... Qual a melhor saida pra isso?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: E como ficaria o action Post no controller? ele receberia o modelo ou uma lista?

Comment: Ele recebe o Model inteiro.

Comment: Mas aqui, não sei porque não esta gravando o que esta sendo armazenado no ICollection, os dados que estão indo pro banco são somente aqueles que estão declarados fora do ICollecion... Teria como atualizar a resposta com um breve exemplo?

Comment: @MatheusSilva Veja agora.

Comment: Hmmm, então acredito que tenha algum erro no meu ViewModel, porque quando coloco assim e dou o comando para adicionar ao modelo original (db.Candidato.Add(candidatoNovo)), aponta um erro, algo como "The best overloaded method match for..."

Comment: Acho que é o caso de mais uma pergunta.