# Como resolver o erro: The best overloaded method match for

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Seguindo os modelos [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97462/problemas-ao-gerar-uma-partialview-com-begincollectionitem/97474), quando passo os comandos para gravar os dados do formulario no banco de dados, antes mesmo de copilar o Visual Studio, aponta o seguinte erro:

**"The best overloaded method match for [...] has some invalid arguments"**

Segue os exemplos do controller (*lembrando qe a view e viewmodel estão na pergunta linkada no começo*)

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Novo()
    {
        ViewBag.Nacionalidade = new SelectList(db.Util.Where(u => u.tipo == 14), "id", "nome");

        var candidato = new CandidatoViewModel();

        return View(candidato);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Novo(CandidatoViewModel candidato)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {         
            db.Candidato.Add(candidato); // erro esta aqui

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("VerCandidato", new { id = candidato.id });            
        }

        ViewBag.Nacionalidade = new SelectList(db.Util.Where(u => u.tipo == 14), "id", "nome", candidato.id_nacionalidade);

        return View(candidato);
    }
```

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre este erro?

Comment: O erro em questão ocorre quando você passa parâmetros inválidos ao chamar um método por exemplo.

Comment: Ta ali no codigo Cigano, comentada "db.Candidato.Add(candidato)//erro esta aqui"

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior Mas meu ViewModel e Model tem exatamente as mesmas propriedades, com exceção da Lista que usei no viewModel e no  model nao tem... Eu ainda não entendi muito bem como é feito esse mapeamento quando se tem múltiplos models, se tiverem artigos/docs para referencia e estudos ia ser de grande ajuda, sem ser aqueles do codeproject...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bom, não vai funcionar, por óbvio. Você está tentando adicionar `CandidatoViewModel` ao contexto, mas um *ViewModel* não é mapeado por contexto por definição.

O correto seria você fazer:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Novo(CandidatoViewModel candidato)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {         
        Candidato candidatoModel = candidato;
        db.Candidato.Add(candidatoModel); 

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("VerCandidato", new { id = candidato.id });            
    }

    ViewBag.Nacionalidade = new SelectList(db.Util.Where(u => u.tipo == 14), "id", "nome", candidato.id_nacionalidade);

    return View(candidato);
}
```

Isto:

```
Candidato candidatoModel = candidato;
```

É valido se você [implementar um operador implícito](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/z5z9kes2.aspx), da seguinte forma:

```
public class Candidato
{
    // Aqui vão as declarações normais do Model

    public static implicit operator Candidato(CandidatoViewModel c)
    {
        return new Candidato {
            Nome = c.Nome,
            Idade = c.Idade,
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Há ainda quem use [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) ao invés de usar um operador implícito, mas opinativamente falando, não sou muito fã.

Comment: Eu sou obrigado a explicitar os campos mesmo sendo exatamente as mesmas nomenclaturas?

Comment: E porque não é muito fã do AutoMapper?

Comment: Não, pode usar com os mesmos, se quiser. AutoMapper eu tentei usar aqui e me deu problemas, principalmente com 1 pra N, que é exatamente o seu caso.